# getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the value of this state object by using a foreach loop. now when I use a map func it works fine. but getting the error when I use the foreach loop.
state object is

```
state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
    ],
  };

handleReset = () => {
    var counters = this.state.counters.forEach((c) => {
      c.value = 0;
    });
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method forEach mutates original array, while map makes new mutated array from the original array. In your case map is the right approach. You can't mutate state directly with forEach.